# org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed

Tags: java, database, quartz-scheduler, derby

Im getting the below mentioned error while running my web application with quartz scheduler.

I'm using two database connection and for quartz, i'm want to use derby so I gave derby transaction manager in my config file.

What is the issue in this config file, How the quartz scheduler is trying to access the DB.

My config file is as follows,:

> 

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.chase.index" />

<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager" />
<bean id="cacheManager"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/resources/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate properties -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties">
</bean>

<!-- Datasource setup by Spring -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/example"
    cache="true" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="false"
    proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" 
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
    p:password="${jdbc.password}"> </bean> -->

<bean id="customerSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <!-- <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" 
        /> -->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.chase.index</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<jee:jndi-lookup id="derbyDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/derbyDataSource"
    cache="true" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="false"
    proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<bean id="derbySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="derbyDataSource"></property>
    <!-- <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" 
        /> -->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.chase.index</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<util:map id="dataSourceMap">
    <entry key="customerSessionFactory" value-ref="customerSessionFactory" />
    <entry key="derbySessionFactory" value-ref="derbySessionFactory" />
</util:map>

<bean id="paramTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="derbySessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="customerSessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<!-- <bean id="runMeJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="targetObject" ref="runMeTask" /> <property name="targetMethod" 
    value="printMe" /> </bean> -->

<bean id="runMeTask" class="com.chase.index.scheduler.SyncDBDataTask" />

<bean name="runMeJob"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">

    <property name="jobClass" value="com.chase.index.scheduler.SyncDBDataJob" />

    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="runMeTask" value-ref="runMeTask" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean"> 
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" /> <property name="repeatInterval" 
    value="5000" /> <property name="startDelay" value="1000" /> </bean> -->

<bean id="cronTrigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />

</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="paramTransactionManager" />
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="runMeJob" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: Table/View 'QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS' does not exist. [See nested exception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table/View 'QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS' does not exist.]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:681)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: Table/View 'QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS' does not exist. [See nested exception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table/View 'QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS' does not exist.]
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:322)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:514)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>       ... 42 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table/View 'QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS' does not exist.
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:146)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:73)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectJobDetail(StdJDBCDelegate.java:839)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1385)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$9.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:1377)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:245)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeWithoutLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3723)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1374)
>       at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.getJobDetail(QuartzScheduler.java:1518)
>       at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.getJobDetail(StdScheduler.java:498)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:191)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.jobDetailExists(SchedulerAccessor.java:416)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.addJobToScheduler(SchedulerAccessor.java:341)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:284)
>       ... 45 more
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS' does not exist.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:125)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:94)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:67)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:94)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:140)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
>       ... 69 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Table/View 'QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS' does not exist.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
>       ... 85 more

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar exception recently when deploying an application on JBoss EAP 7.3.

```
ERROR XXXXXX.systemupdate.internal.ApplicationStateInitializer - [User:unknown] Error in determineAndSetApplicationState: 
 XXXXXX.common.beans.NoSuchBeanException: The requested bean(s) of type 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean' could not be found.
    at XXXXXX.spring.SpringBeanFactoryAdapter.getBeansOfType(SpringBeanFactoryAdapter.java:77)
    at XXXXXX.common.beans.BeanLocator.getBeansOfType(BeanLocator.java:113)
    at XXXXXX.systemupdate.internal.SystemUpdateContributorController.startSchedulerJobs(SystemUpdateContributorController.java:376)
    at XXXXXX.systemupdate.internal.SystemUpdateContributorController.setApplicationStateToReady(SystemUpdateContributorController.java:369)
    at XXXXXX.systemupdate.internal.ApplicationStateInitializer.determineAndSetApplicationState(ApplicationStateInitializer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1854)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clusterSchedulerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [XXX.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: oracle/sql/BLOB
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300)
    at XXXXXX.spring.SpringBeanFactoryAdapter.getBeansOfType(SpringBeanFactoryAdapter.java:74)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: oracle/sql/BLOB
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:265)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:505)
    at XXXXXX.scheduling.QuartzConfig.afterPropertiesSet(QuartzConfig.java:45)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 59 more
```

Debugging (spring is swallowing the exception) revealed the root cause

```
  at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
  at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
  at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
  at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.sql.BLOB from [Module "deployment.XXXX.war" from Service Module Loader]
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
```

Turned out that I forgot to register the oracle driver as a global module by adding the following after `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">` in standalone.xml

```
<global-modules>
  <module name="com.oracle" slot="main"/>
</global-modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your issue is `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS' does not exist`

Check whether the table `QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS` is present in the database schema which you are connecting to. Also verify whether the credentials with which you are accessing this schema has access to this table.

Comment: yes, It is SQLSyntaxErrorException, but should i need to create a  QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS table? with what columns? and what are all the constraints?

Comment: http://www.spacewalkproject.org/documentation/schema-doc/table-QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS.html. This may help

Comment: Thank you.. But why is that need to create a table for quartz scheduler? It means, when ever we are using quartz scheduler, we need to create this table mannually?

Comment: Yes. If you are going with Jobstore you need to have this and related tables as well.

Comment: Even I tried by creating tables but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Quartz Api 2+ then you have to care about following steps:

- Replace JobDetailBean to JobDetailFactoryBean
- Replace CronTriggerBean to CronTriggerFactoryBean

You also need to do the following:

If you are getting durability error during bean initialisation then used

- `<property name="durability" value="true"/>`

  in job bean.